# Error - UnboundLocalError at /home/ local variable 'team1_score' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

Getting this error on django

This is my views.py

```
def post(self, request):  
    form = BetForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        team1_score = form.cleaned_data.get('team1_score')
        team2_score = form.cleaned_data.get('team2_score')
        match = form.cleaned_data.get('match')
        form = BetForm()
        return redirect ('index')
    args = {'form': form, 'team1_score': team1_score, 'team2_score': team2_score, 'match': match}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

This is my forms.py

```
class BetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    team1_score = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=15)
    team2_score = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=15)

    class Meta:
        model = Bet
        fields = ('team1_score', 'team2_score', 'match')
```

The error is on this line:

```
args = {'form': form, 'team1_score': team1_score, 'team2_score':
```

Comment: if `form.is_valid()` you returnd `redirect ('index')` in other situation `team1_score` is Undefined

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is unclear, but with your code only there will be errors indeed : the line you mention where error occurs :

```
    args = {'form': form, 'team1_score': team1_score, etc.
```

This line is outside of your "if" loop --> the variables defined in your "if" loop don't exist outside of it. If you need to send them in your "render" function, then variables must exist. At this stage, only your "form" variable is defined.